# How to determine normal indices to complex bodies using loops?

Tags: c++, loops, geometry, square, vertices

```
if (i >= 0 && i <= NX - 1 && j == 0)
{
   phase[i*NY + j] = phase[i * NY + (j + 1)];
}
```

NX and NY are integers. As you can see, `phase[i * NY + (j + 1)]` accesses the vertices next to the wall, where wall vertices are accessed by the `if` loop as `if (i >= 0 && i <= NX - 1 && j == 0)` (bottom wall). Here it is simple, but for complex bodies (square, triangle, circle), how can I access the NORMAL/Perpendicular vertices outside the body using `for` loop? In image, how can I access red vertices with the help of black vertices?

square with unknown

[image]

Comment: What are the NY and NX variables?

Comment: it's also unclear   what do you mean by "normal vertices"

Comment: Do you mean normal as in orthogonal to the surface? But I assume your question is to broad, it would require much more informationen about your program and data structure to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: NX and NY are integers. Normal vertices meaning perpendicular vertices. Please let me know if things are not clear still.

Comment: why you added `j` to indices when the condition has `j==0` in it?

Comment: @Afshin. by adding 1 to j on the right side of the equation, I can access the elements/indices/vertices next to the wall. My question is how can I access the next elements to bodies other than wall? I have demonstrated how can I access the next elements to a wall in my example.

Comment: How other "bodies" are described? With some kind of grid?

Comment: I can realize grid for rectangle or square ([arbitrary example](https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fe5b%2Fe5b8094e-94fc-4100-898f-d2f623c69670%2FphpHY3XDz.png)). But what about circle or complex figure? Give us more details please.

Comment: @MBo. for square, for example," if(i >= 5 && i <= 8 && j >= 21 && j <= 24)". This condition will draw a square. In other words  if(i >= xStart && i <= xStop && j >= yStart && j <= yStop)" will draw a square. Here, xStart, xStop, yStart and yStop are integers. outside vertices would be as follows. if( i == 3, j >= 20 && j <= 25),    
 if( i == 9, j >= 20 && j <= 25), if(i >= 3 && i <= 9 && j == 20), and if(i >= 3 && i <= 9 && j == 25). But this method is very bad, especially for circle and other complex bodies.

Comment: @MBo. Is above explanation enough? Or I can Draw a square and explain more easily.

Comment: Everybody knows how rectangular grid looks. You'd better to describe your real problem, show real pictures.

Comment: @MBo. Sir I have added picture in my Question section to explain real problem

Comment: OK, I modified question to make the picture visible. I hope somebody will understand your needs.